# NodeJS executable file can't receives command args via `process.argv`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I have create a node [repository](https://github.com/khai-test-repositories/test-npm-bin-argv) directly on github.com site, then I run `npm install -g khai-test-repositories/test-npm-bin-argv`.

The problem is, when I run `test-npm-bin-argv abc def ghi` in Windows Command Prompt, it shows only node path and executable javascript file, doesn't shows `abc`, `def` nor `ghi`

Am I do something wrong? Should I file a bug?

## My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-npm-bin-argv",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "bin": "bin.js"
}
```

## My bin.js

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

## Versions

- npm version (`npm --version`): 3.7.3
- node version (`node --version`): 5.8.0
- OS Version (`dxdiag`): Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 10586)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in first line of your bin.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you tell me more details about it, e.g. why that line is necessary?

Comment: Will give you link to Python answer. [Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script). It explains perfectly what this line means, just for other language. You can apply it for node also, just change 'python' to 'node' :)